# Why am I getting a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, android, collections

I have a workout tracker app.

A user can record exercises (e.g. weight,reps).

It is working correctly, however when you change between months and then modify a recorded exercise (e.g. delete/ update) or record a new exercise, the app crashes.

I am getting a `concurrentModificationException`.

I have read some articles on the error message, however I still do not know why I am getting the error.

Why am I getting a `concurrentModificationException`?

**Error Message:**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:136)
        at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:588)
        at com.example.exerciseappv5.CalendarCode.CustomCalendarView.checkIfWeekCompleted(CustomCalView.java:181)
        at com.example.exerciseappv5.CalendarCode.CustomCalendarView.lambda$ChangeMonth$0$CustomCalView(CustomCalView.java:167)
```

**The line where the error occurs:**

`if (completedDates.equals("100")) {completedDatesList.addAll(thisWeekDates);}`

**CustomCalendarView** (RelevantCode)

```
 public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {

 
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> datesFormattedList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> logDatesList = new ArrayList<>();

    CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> completedDatesList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>
();
    ArrayList<String> uniqueDatesWithLogEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> listOfWeeks = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(final Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        InitializeLayout();
        SetUpCalendar();

        PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                SetUpCalendar();
            }
        });

        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                SetUpCalendar();
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                final String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));
                final ArrayList<String> arrayListDateFormattedList = (ArrayList<String>) datesFormattedList;
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WorkoutButtonsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_DATE, date);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES, arrayListDateFormattedList);
                getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void InitializeLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, this);
        NextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        PreviousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousBtn);
        CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_Date);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    }

    void SetUpCalendar() {

        datesFormattedList.clear();
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());  // e.g. July 2020
        CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
        dates.clear();
        Calendar monthCalendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        monthCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        int FirstDayofMonth = monthCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;
        monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -FirstDayofMonth);

        while (dates.size() < MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS) {
            dates.add(monthCalendar.getTime());
            monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        /*CONVERTS THE LIST OF ALL VISIBLE DATES TO A STRING */
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS; i++) {
            final String dateFormatted = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(i));
            datesFormattedList.add(dateFormatted);
        }
        ChangeMonth();
    }

    public void ChangeMonth() {
        completedDatesList.clear();
        listOfWeeks.clear();
        //Break Down month dates into weeks
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(0, 7));          //1
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(7, 14));         //2
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(14, 21));        //3
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(21, 28));        //4
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(28, 35));        //5
        listOfWeeks.add(datesFormattedList.subList(35, 42));        //6

        // For loop query to check the percentage completion fo each week
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfWeeks.size(); i++) {
            List<String> thisWeekDates =  listOfWeeks.get(i);
            workoutCompletionPercentageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(WorkoutCompletionPercentageViewModel.class);
            workoutCompletionPercentageViewModel.getWeekCompletionPercentage(thisWeekDates).observe((FragmentActivity) context,
                    completedDates -> checkIfWeekCompleted(completedDates, thisWeekDates)
            );
        }

        //Observe data from log entry view model to determine whether calendar date has a log entry
        logEntriesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(LogEntriesViewModel.class);
        logEntriesViewModel.setFilter(datesFormattedList);
        logEntriesViewModel.getDatesFilteredByMonth().observe((FragmentActivity) context, logDates -> setData(logDates));
    }

    public void checkIfWeekCompleted(String weekCompletion, List<String> thisWeekDates) {

        if (weekCompletion.equals("100")) {
            completedDatesList.addAll(thisWeekDates);
        }
    }

    private void setData(List<String> logDates) {

        logDatesList.clear();
        logDatesList.addAll(logDates);
        Set<String> setWithUniqueValues = new HashSet<>(logDatesList);
        uniqueDatesWithLogEntries = new ArrayList<>(setWithUniqueValues);
        myGridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(context, dates, calendar, uniqueDatesWithLogEntries, completedDatesList);
        gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);
    }
}
```

**MyGridAdapter** (I'm not sure if this is relevant)

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List<Date> dates;
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> completedDates;
    Calendar currentDate;
    List<String> logs;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView fire;
    LayerDrawable bottomBorder;

    private WorkoutCompletionPercentageViewModel workoutCompletionPercentageViewModel;

    public MyGridAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Date> dates, Calendar currentDate, List<String> logs, CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> completedDates) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_cell_layout);

        this.completedDates = completedDates;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
        this.logs = logs;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Date monthDate = dates.get(position);
        Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateCalendar.setTime(monthDate);
        int DayNo = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int displayMonth = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int displayYear = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int currentYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentDay = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_cell_layout, parent, false);
        }

        fire = view.findViewById(R.id.fire);
        fire.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (displayMonth == currentMonth && displayYear == currentYear) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
        }

        ImageView calendarTick = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarTick);

        Calendar eventCalendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
       // ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++) {
            eventCalendar2.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(logs.get(i)));
            if (DayNo == eventCalendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && displayMonth == eventCalendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
                    && displayYear == eventCalendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
              //  arrayList.add(logs.get(i));
                calendarTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  // Instead of this we show a circle which was invisible
            }
        }

//SET THE CALENDAR BACKGROUND IF WEEK IS COMPLETED

        Calendar eventCalendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
     //   ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < completedDates.size(); i++) {
            eventCalendar3.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(completedDates.get(i)));
            if (DayNo == eventCalendar3.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && displayMonth == eventCalendar3.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
                    && displayYear == eventCalendar3.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
             //   arrayList2.add(completedDates.get(i));

                //SETTING THE BORDER AROUND COMPLETED WEEKS
                String backgroundHex;
                fire.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (displayMonth == currentMonth && displayYear == currentYear) {
                    backgroundHex = "#1DB954";

                } else {
                    backgroundHex = "#cccccc";
                }

                GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
                bottomBorder = getBorders(
                        Color.parseColor(backgroundHex), // Background color
                        Color.parseColor("#ffd700"), // Border color
                        0, // Left border in pixels
                        5, // Top border in pixels
                        0, // Right border in pixels
                        5 // Bottom border in pixels
                );

                // Finally, apply the drawable as text view background
                view.setBackground(bottomBorder);
            }
        }

        Calendar eventCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        TextView Day_Number = view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day);
        Day_Number.setText(String.valueOf(DayNo));

        if (DayNo == currentDay && displayMonth == eventCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 && displayYear == eventCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            Day_Number.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF33"));
        }
        return view;
    }

    private Date ConvertStringToDate(String eventDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(eventDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dates.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(@Nullable Object item) {
        return dates.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dates.get(position);
    }

    // Custom method to generate one or multi side border for a view
    protected LayerDrawable getBorders(int bgColor, int borderColor,
                                       int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        // Initialize new color drawables
        ColorDrawable borderColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(borderColor);
        ColorDrawable backgroundColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(bgColor);

        // Initialize a new array of drawable objects
        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[]{
                borderColorDrawable,
                backgroundColorDrawable
        };

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drawables);
        layerDrawable.setLayerInset(
                1, // Index of the drawable to adjust [background color layer]
                left, // Number of pixels to add to the left bound [left border]
                top, // Number of pixels to add to the top bound [top border]
                right, // Number of pixels to add to the right bound [right border]
                bottom // Number of pixels to add to the bottom bound [bottom border]
        );
        return layerDrawable;
    }
}
```

Comment: most likely `MyGridAdapter` has an Iterator open on `completedDatesList` while you modify it.

Comment: How can I identify what is causing the error?

Comment: The stack trace tells you *exactly* ***where*** the error is occurring: `CustomCalendarView.checkIfWeekCompleted(CustomCalView.java:181)`. Start there.

Comment: what is the end type of completedDatesList?

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> completedDatesList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you are modifying the completedDates list while reading it - most likely some UI components are reading it. The easy solution could be to use CopyOnWriteArrayList for completedDates or more complex - to keep 2 versions of lists - one which you are going to modify and another which you are going to read. Once modifications done you update the read version.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have tried to create a new list (I have updated my code to show this, however I am still getting the error. Where about's should I be updating the read version?

Comment: I am also getting the same error after changing completedDatesList to CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: @JoshBrett could you add the code where you initialize completedDates? CopyOnWriteArrayList should work for you unless you initialize it with something else. Please check in debugger what is the end type of completedDates.

Comment: I have added the initialisation.

Comment: Have I missed anything?

Comment: it is quite strange, are you sure that you rebuild your classes, please try clean build to make sure old code is not running there

Comment: I have rebuilt and cleaned, I have also completely reset my device, however the `ConcurrentModificationException` still persists.

Comment: How do I implement the other way which you suggested?

Comment: the problem msot likely in something else, can you add your code to github?